# How to install getnonfreefonts on Windows with MiKTeX?

Tags: fonts, errors, scripts

I was trying to install a non-free font for LaTeX. The website https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/ tells me that I should use a script `install-getnonfreefonts`.

When I've launched it with `texlua` I've got an error:

```
.\install-getnonfreefonts:877: attempt to concatenate a nil value (global 'texdir')
```

I'm not an expert in LaTeX, so I don't know what to do. `texdir` probably means installation directory?

Comment: Shouldn't the fonts already be in miktex itself? I thought it was less strict about licenses.

Comment: Which font specifically do you need?

Comment: I don't think getnonfreefonts supports anything other than TeXLive, see https://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/, miktex is not mentioned on that page.

Comment: @daleif, probably, you are right. You can post this as answer. I'll use WSL with TeXLive